# How to get the GUI activity of an application using Java

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, java-native-interface, jna

Is there a way to track the gui idleness and activity of a given application in Java. I have done this using C# referring this tutorial:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13756/Detecting-Application-Idleness
How do I do it in Java?

Comment: This would require that you communicate directly with the operating system (OS), and since Java was built to be as OS agnostic as possible, it is not as easy to do this with Java. If this functionality is absolutely necessary, consider looking into using JNI or JNA (my preference) to assist you. Google can lead you to the tutorials on these guys.

Answer (score 1):

If you can modify the application you can install your own EventQueue - [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html#push(java.awt.EventQueue)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html#push%28java.awt.EventQueue%29) - processing UI events and paint requests. If changing the application is not possible you can still do similar thing with JVMTI (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jvmti/). The implementation will be a bit more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

This answer applied to Windows.

Here are a few snippets that should get you started.  This code is for example only and is not complete.  The complete solution is lengthy.

Jump from Java to the native side and make a call to 
CallNtPowerInformation() requesting SystemPowerInformation.
Pass the results up to the Java side.

```
    ntStatus = CallNtPowerInformation(SystemPowerInformation, lpInputBuffer, nInputBufferSize, &systemPowerInformation, systemPowerInformationSize);
    success = ntStatus == STATUS_SUCCESS;
    if (success == FALSE) {
        logErrorMessage(thisFunctionName, ntStatus);
    } else {
        SYSTEM_POWER_INFORMATION * p = (SYSTEM_POWER_INFORMATION *) &systemPowerInformation;
        javaDefineLong(env, o, "SYSTEM_POWER_INFORMATION.CoolingMode", 0, p->CoolingMode);
        javaDefineLong(env, o, "SYSTEM_POWER_INFORMATION.Idleness", 0, p->Idleness);
        javaDefineLong(env, o, "SYSTEM_POWER_INFORMATION.TimeRemaining", 0, p->TimeRemaining);
        javaDefineLong(env, o, "SYSTEM_POWER_INFORMATION.MaxIdlenessAllowed", 0, p->MaxIdlenessAllowed);
    }
```

Do the same for ProcessorInformation.

```
ntStatus = CallNtPowerInformation(ProcessorInformation, lpInputBuffer, nInputBufferSize, &processorPowerInformation, processorPowerInformationSize);
    success = ntStatus == STATUS_SUCCESS;
    if (success == FALSE) {
        logErrorMessage(thisFunctionName, ntStatus);
    } else {
        int x;
        for (x=0; x!=32; x++) {
            PROCESSOR_POWER_INFORMATION * p = (PROCESSOR_POWER_INFORMATION *) &(processorPowerInformation[x]);
            if (x != p->Number) {
                break;
            }
            else {
                javaDefineLong(env, o, "PROCESSOR_POWER_INFORMATION.CurrentIdleState", x, p->CurrentIdleState);
                javaDefineLong(env, o, "PROCESSOR_POWER_INFORMATION.CurrentMhz", x, p->CurrentMhz);
                javaDefineLong(env, o, "PROCESSOR_POWER_INFORMATION.MaxIdleState", x, p->MaxIdleState);
                javaDefineLong(env, o, "PROCESSOR_POWER_INFORMATION.MaxMhz", x, p->MaxMhz);
                javaDefineLong(env, o, "PROCESSOR_POWER_INFORMATION.MhzLimit", x, p->MhzLimit);
                javaDefineLong(env, o, "PROCESSOR_POWER_INFORMATION.Number", x, p->Number);
            }
        }
    }
```

Do the same for SystemPowerPolicyCurrent.

```
ntStatus = CallNtPowerInformation(SystemPowerPolicyCurrent, lpInputBuffer, nInputBufferSize, &systemPowerPolicy, systemPowerPolicySize);
    success = ntStatus == STATUS_SUCCESS;
    if (success == FALSE) {
        logErrorMessage(thisFunctionName, ntStatus);
    } else {
        SYSTEM_POWER_POLICY * p = (SYSTEM_POWER_POLICY *) &systemPowerPolicy;
        javaDefineLong(env, o, "SYSTEM_POWER_POLICY.VideoTimeout", 0, p->VideoTimeout);
        javaDefineLong(env, o, "SYSTEM_POWER_POLICY.IdleTimeout", 0, p->IdleTimeout);
        javaDefineLong(env, o, "SYSTEM_POWER_POLICY.LidClose.Action", 0, p->LidClose.Action);
        javaDefineLong(env, o, "SYSTEM_POWER_POLICY.IdleSensitivity", 0, p->IdleSensitivity);
        javaDefineLong(env, o, "SYSTEM_POWER_POLICY.PowerButton.Action", 0, p->PowerButton.Action);
    }
```

Back to the Java side.  Calculate Idle & Busy.

```
final long id = Java2WinPower.longs.get("SYSTEM_POWER_INFORMATION.Idleness.0").longValue();
final long is = Java2WinPower.longs.get("SYSTEM_POWER_POLICY.IdleSensitivity.0").longValue();
final float aboveT = id - is;
final float belowT = is - id;
final float hi = 100 - is;
final float lo = is;
final int a = (int) ((aboveT / hi) * 100);
final int b = (int) ((belowT / lo) * 100);

 textID.setText(a == b ? "" : a > b ? ("Idle:" + a + "%") : ("Busy:" + b + "%"));
```

Here is a static view.  Real view is, of course, dynamic.

[image]

There are degrees of Idle and Busy.  For example, idle of 30% is more idle compared to idle of 5%.
Same for busy.  Busy of 50% is busier than a busy of 5%.  The SleepTimer you see in the image is a countdown timer when the computer is allowed to sleep or hibernate.  All data comes from the OS.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer.Is there a way to track if the user has opened an app having it idle for a long time? I mean how long the app is idle and how mcuh memory it consumed?

Comment: Well, the above solution is for System Idle/Busy.  So if a user is not using the computer, the computer will switch to some idle %.  But if the user stops using your app, and starts using another app, the solution will report busy.  So when you say, "How long the app is idle", do you mean how long has it been since your main JFrame has been updated?  Or how long has it been since a user pressed a key? Or how long has it been since a user used the mouse? or what?

Comment: I am not looking into my Java App. I want monitor any application that is running but is idle.Idle here could be identified by both how long it has been since a key was pressed or mouse was moved. Any ideas on this?

Comment: I don't know how a Java application can monitor the keyboard and mouse activity of an arbitrary application.  Your question should be "How can I monitor the keyboard and mouse of an arbitrary (Java or NonJava) application?" Now...think about what you are asking. How about an app monitoring YOUR application. How would you feel about this app knowing your browser keyboard activity as you log on to your banking account?

Answer (score 0):

Radim's answer is correct if you would like to only monitor your java application for activity.  If you would like to monitor the entire system for user activity as suggested by Hovercraft Full Of Eels, you will need some native code.  You should be able to leverage something like [JNativeHook](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook) to accomplish the latter.